# By _all_ statement in SAS: explanation please

Tags: sorting, duplicates, sas

One (perhaps silly) question about how SAS does process data if instructed with a **by *all*** statement. Take the following code as an example:

```
DATA ESPERIMENTO;
INPUT NOME $ ID ETA;
DATALINES;
FABRIZIO 10 12
FABRIZIO 10 12
FABRIZIO 10 12
FABRIZIO 10 11
FABRIZIO 11 12
FABRIZIO 11 12
FABRIZIO 10 11
MATTIA 11 11
MATTIA 11 11
MATTIA 11 11
GIULIA 12 12
GIULIA 11 12
GIULIA 12 11
GIULIA 12 12
;
RUN;

PROC SORT DATA=WORK.ESPERIMENTO OUT=ESPERIMENTO; BY _ALL_; RUN;

DATA CONTEGGIO;
SET ESPERIMENTO;
BY _ALL_;
    IF FIRST.NOME THEN COUNT_NOME=0; COUNT_NOME + 1;
    IF FIRST.ID THEN COUNT_ID=0; COUNT_ID + 1;
    IF FIRST.ETA THEN COUNT_ETA=0; COUNT_ETA + 1;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=CONTEGGIO; TITLE "PRINT_OF_CONTEGGIO"; RUN;
```

I get the following output

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKt7G.png)

Now, my questions are:

- why does SAS seem to identify fully duplicated rows/observations only if the first. command is applied to the right-most variable of the table?
- if, as I always understood, SAS processes a by statement based upon the variables listed in such statement, why can't I write something like first.*all*?
- or, on the contrary, why does SAS seem to have memory only of variables sorted to the left to the variable I write into the first. statement, while not to the right of it?
- last: if my understanding of how does SAS work (if instructed with a by command) is correct, a first. statement should take into account only the variable specified within it; then why, if I write into the first. statement (after the by statement) the rightmost variable, SAS seems to compare rows/observation as a whole?
- **in other words**, and much more concisely: **can anybody explain to me why COUNT_NOME, COUNT_ID and COUNT_ETA are all different?**

Thank you so much in advance to anyone who will be so kind to answer and explain.

Comment: What is it you want to "count"?

Comment: Suggest you add `put _all_ ;` to your data step.  This will show you the value of first.nome first.id first.eta for each record.  Or to show less variables: `put (NOME ID ETA first.NOME first.ID first.ETA)(=) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context `_all_` is VARIABLE LIST.  It means every variable in the dataset.

So if the dataset only has the variables NOME, ID and ETA (in that ORDER) then it is the same as:

```
by NOME ID ETA;
```

As to why the counts are different, that is because they are counting different things.

So if the BY variables are (NOME ID ETA) in that order then COUNT_NOM will number the observations within in each level of NOME.  But COUNT_ID will number the observation within each level of ID*NOME combination. etc.

When NOME changes value then FIRST.NOME is true, and also FIRST.ID is true even if the value of ID did not change.  Because ID is nested under NOME in the BY statement.

Comment: Thanks Tom! So, if my understanding is correct: in a by statement, if you list more than one variable, then SAS will:
1) count, on any variable listed in the by statement, FIRST and LAST taking into account ALL the variables listed before the variable you are writing after FIRST/LAST;
2) when comparing observations (either to compute FIRST/LAST or to delete duplicate, like in NODUPKEY), it will not limit itself to contrasting lines only on the explicitly stated variable (or the last variable of the list), but it will compare lines w.r.t all the variables listed up until the explicit one.